# Annotate values above bar - R

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, bar-chart

> Possible Duplicates: But all were explained for faceted bar plot, and mine is normal bar-chart
>   [Annotation of summary statistic on ggplot above bars on barchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23210834/annotation-of-summary-statistic-on-ggplot-above-bars-on-barchart),
>   [Annotation above bars:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327267/annotation-above-bars)

I want to annotate **maximum** value above the bar. (Could use **mean** value in same case)

For Example (could skip), There was a game played at a school. Students have to throw water balloon at defined target. Each student got 4 chances and in each chance he/she can throw 10 balloons. At last, maximum from the four scores will be considered.

*Data Set*:

```
> Balloon_throw
    Student Score
1   Raju    4
2   Guddu   5
3   Pinky   4
4   Daina   6
5   Pappu   3
6   Raju    6
7   Guddu   5
8   Pinky   5
9   Daina   7
10  Pappu   4
11  Raju    5
12  Guddu   6
13  Pinky   4
14  Daina   6
15  Pappu   5
16  Raju    5
17  Guddu   7
18  Pinky   8
19  Daina   7
20  Pappu   5
```

I want to create a bar graph which show the maximum score obtained by particular student with a bar and **only** annotate his/her **maximum score on top of the bar**.

```
qplot(x = Student, y = Score, data= Balloon_throw, geom="bar", stat="summary", fun.y = "max", position="dodge", xlab="Student name", ylab = "Water Balloon hits", main = "Result of water balloon throwing game",fill= factor(Student))+geom_text(aes(label=Score, x = Student, y = Score), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image: Annotation is shown top 3 values, I want the maximum score]

Comment: What kind of geom_bar is that? Are you plotting only max values on y-axis?

Comment: @Pgibas : Yes, using `qplot` and `fun.y = "max"`

Answer (score 1):

Get only the Max. value

```
> Balloon_throw <- ddply(Balloon_throw, "Student", subset, Score==max(Score))
  Student Score
1   Daina     7
2   Daina     7
3   Guddu     7
4   Pappu     5
5   Pappu     5
6   Pinky     8
7    Raju     6
```

Remove the Duplicates

```
> Balloon_throw <- Balloon_throw[!duplicated(Balloon_throw),]
> Balloon_throw
  Student Score
1   Daina     7
3   Guddu     7
4   Pappu     5
6   Pinky     8
7    Raju     6
qplot(x = Student, y = Score, data= Balloon_throw, geom="bar", stat="summary", fun.y = "max", position="dodge", xlab="Student name", ylab = "Water Balloon hits", main = "Result of water balloon throwing game",fill= factor(Student))+geom_text(aes(label=Score, x = Student, y = Score), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: I am not able to apply the same trick (jugaad) in case of mean. This is just a sample data, I want to learn the logic behind it. Could you please correct me at `geom_text` or suggest some alternative?

Comment: I had mentioned in the question. I want  to annotate maximum, mean, minimum value etc on top of bar. `ddply` is working fine in case of maximum and minimum, but isn't working for mean values.

Comment: > Balloon_throw <- ddply(Balloon_throw,~Student,summarise,Score=mean(Score)) 
 Student Score
1   Daina  6.50
2   Guddu  5.75
3   Pappu  4.25
4   Pinky  5.25
5    Raju  5.00

Comment: @AshvinMeena i have given for mean - if this answer your ur question , select the answer as correct and upvote

Comment: It's okay to approve edits on your answer. It won't harm your reputation. :-)

Comment: @AshvinMeena :) Its ok to accept the solution as answer. If you feel , it solved ur purpose. And its not in my control/hands to approve ur suggested edits.Not sure who has it.

Comment: I had up-voted your Answer&Comment because of your approach. But I got my answer without manipulating input data. `stat_bin` alternative of `geom_text` and `text` in case of normal `barplot`. So, I have left the question open for answers.